# CSS background doesnt show color

Tags: html, css

I am following a tutorial from YouTube. There I followed the same procedure. I checked it several times. But the video's authors background color shows up and mine doesn't. I have tried overflow, clear etc but it doesn't work. People with big brains I need help?

here is the css code:

```
*{
       
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container{

             width: 100%;
             height: 100%;
             background: #42455a;
}
```

And here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Crypto Currency Web App - Easy Tutorials</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
       
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: problem resolved. The solution was to specify the html and body height

like

````
              height:100%;
              padding:0;
              margin: 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Crypto Currency Web App - Easy Tutorials</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p> just write something to here your width and height percent not fixed size </p>
       
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

if you want to see the container then  your CSS should be following:

```
.container{

             width: 100px;
             height: 100px;
             background: #42455a;
}
```

100 px is a just example you can enter what you want

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{       
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container{

             width: 100%;
             height: 100%;
             background: #42455a;min-height:145px;
             color:#fff;padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Crypto Currency Web App - Easy Tutorials</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        You need to insert some content or add some CSS like min-height to empty div to show background color
       
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```